# Validating textbox using javascript in MasterPage

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I am using javascript for customValidator to validate textboxes in ASP.Net.
The code works perfectly when I am using a normal page, but as soon as I put that inside a MasterPage, the code doesn't work.

Below is the code for my aspx page. If I put this code inside a MasterPage it doesn't work.
Could you guys advise me how to make this work inside a MasterPage

Thanks,
Abhi.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
 function validateOrFields(source, args){
 var sUser = document.getElementById('TextBox1');

   if (sUser.value == "")
   {
      args.IsValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      args.IsValid = true;
   }  
   return;  
 }
```

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"
        runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="FieldValidator" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Text="Enter either a user name" 
                    ClientValidationFunction="validateOrFields" onservervalidate="FieldValidator_ServerValidate"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the id by using `ClientID`

Replace your code by

```
var sUser = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the ID of the TextBox. When placed in the Master Page, it gets a different ClientID.

```
var sUser = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try document.getElementById('ct100_TextBox1').value. It is just a temporary fix!! But anyone please suggest how to get this ID dynamically using code. I got this by viewing source of the page generated. I have also posted the same question here
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726564/access-a-control-in-master-page-using-javascript-within-the-master-page-itself)